# Is there a way to query all data that a user has access to, when only certain columns are granted via SQL-Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been looking online for a SQL query that gets all data that a given user has access too. Similar to `SELECT * FROM table` but that only queries the columns accessible to that user. How could I go about designing a query that could do that, in the event I do not know what columns a user has or hasn't been granted SELECT permissions for?

So far I've tried `SELECT * ALL` however that queries all columns, resulting in a permission denied error.

Comment: I don't think there is any syntax like that, but have you considered giving the user a view that only has the columns they have permission on? Then `SELECT * FROM view` would work.

Comment: @EdmCoff I had not considered that, I will try it and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating a view, then selecting from that. Thanks To @EdmCoff